# How many triplets of consecutive primes $p$, $q$, $r$ are such that $p^2+q^2+r^2$ is also prime?

Tags: number-theory

> So we have $p$, $q$, $r$ which are successive prime numbers, we wonder how many such triplets are such that $p^2+q^2+r^2$ is also a prime.

My attempt: I tried to $p^2+q^2+r^2$ refactor it somehow, but to no avail.

Comment: There was a missing information. This expression needs to be prime. Edited it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $p,q,r$ are all $\ge 5$, then $p^2\equiv q^2\equiv r^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and so $3\mid p^2+q^2+r^2$. So the only remaining candidates are $2^2+3^2+5^2$ and $3^2+5^2+7^2$.

Comment: Why is $p^2\equiv q^2\equiv r^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$?

Comment: @DarkoDekan If $p \neq 3$ then $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: And one of those remaining candidates is even.  Will the other one work?  The Shadow knows.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

This OCaml program verifies it!

```
type 'a stream= Eos| StrCons of 'a * (unit-> 'a stream)

let rec nums_from n = StrCons(n,fun ()-> nums_from (n+1))

let hdStr (s: 'a stream) : 'a =
  match s with
  | Eos -> failwith "headless stream"
  | StrCons (x,_) -> x;;

let tlStr (s : 'a stream) : 'a stream =
  match s with
  | Eos -> failwith "empty stream"
  | StrCons (x, t) -> t ();;    

let rec listify (s : 'a stream) (n: int) : 'a list =
  if n <= 0 then []
  else
    match s with
    | Eos -> []
    | _ -> (hdStr s) :: listify (tlStr s) (n - 1);;

let rec filterStream (test : 'a -> bool) (astream :'a stream)=
  match astream with
  |Eos -> Eos
  |StrCons (q,w) -> if test q then StrCons(q, fun () -> filterStream test (w () ))
      else filterStream test (w ())

let removenumbermod n =
  filterStream (fun x -> x mod n <>0) 

let rec sieves natural =
  match natural with
  |StrCons(q,w) -> StrCons(q, fun () -> sieves (removenumbermod q (w ())))
  |Eos ->Eos

let isprime n =
  let primes = sieves (nums_from 2) in
  let rec helper nn pp=
    match pp with
    |StrCons(q,w)->if q>nn then false else
        if q=nn then true else helper nn (w ())
    |Eos ->false
  in helper n primes

let primes = sieves (nums_from 2) 

let search_threeconsecutiveprimes (primess : int stream) =
  let rec helper current next rest =
    match rest with
    |Eos->Eos
    |StrCons(q,w)-> let nextofnext = q in
        if isprime (current*current+next*next+nextofnext*nextofnext ) then 
          StrCons((current, next, nextofnext), fun ()-> helper next nextofnext (w()))
        else helper next nextofnext (w ())
  in let fst = hdStr primes 
  in let snd = hdStr (tlStr primes)
  in helper fst snd (tlStr (tlStr primes))

let result = search_threeconsecutiveprimes primes
```

result:

```
search_threeconsecutiveprimes primes ;;

- : (int * int * int) stream = StrCons ((3, 5, 7), <fun>)
```